# Find an equation for the real part of a complex solution of an equation

Tags: polynomials, complex-numbers

If $a$ is the real part of a complex solution for $z^3+2z+1=0$. How can I prove that $8a^3+4a-1=0$?

Comment: What equation does the real part satisfy?

Comment: @copper.hat yes

Comment: Do some work. Write $z=x+iy$ and figure out the equations that $x,y$ solve. Notice something about the $y$ equation which relates to the 'complex solution' part of the question. Then substitute accordingly. In other words, do some work.

Comment: @copper.hat the real and complex parts will then be a mixture of x and y. There is not an equation just based on real or complex parts...

Comment: That is true. That is why you need both sets of equations. Why don't you read my comment and think about it. Especially the 'complex solution' part.

Comment: Another hint: If the $y$ of a solution is non zero, what equation must it satisfy?

Comment: @copper.hat I could be mistaken, but it looks like the problem has $2$ typos in it: [1] The equation should be $8a^3 + 4a - 1 = 0$. [2] The assertion should be that of the $3$ distinct roots of the equation, $z_1, z_2, z_3$, that at least one of the $3$ roots will have a Real component that satisfies the equation.  As written, the assertion reads as if all $3$ of the roots will have Real components that satisfy the equation.

Comment: @user2661923 I think you may be right and I need to eat crow.

Comment: @copper.hat Re my point [2], in my last comment, it depends on how you interpret the phrase: "a real part of a complex solution".  If you interpret that to mean that the constraint only applies to roots whose imaginary component is non-zero, then the assertion holds.

Comment: @MinimusHeximus Can you check if it is $8a^3$ or $8a^2$? If the latter then ignore my impatient comments above.

Comment: @copper.hat yes. It is $a^3$. And I could solve it. thanks.

Comment: Good of @user2661923 to point it out. I didn't even notice that my solution had $8a^3$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\,z_1, z_2, \overline{z_2}\,$ be the roots of $\,z^3+2z+1=0\,$, where $\,z_1 \in \mathbb R\,$ and $\,z_2 \in \mathbb C \setminus \mathbb R\,$. Let the real part of the complex roots be $\,a = \text{Re}(z_2)=\frac{1}{2}(z_2 + \bar z_2)\,$.

Since the cubic is missing the quadratic term, $\,z_1+z_2+\overline{z_2} = 0\,$ by Vieta's relations, so $\,z_1 = -(z_2+\overline{z_2})$ $= -2a\,$. But $\,z_1^3+2z_1+1=0\,$, therefore $\,(-2a)^3+ 2\cdot(-2a) + 1 = 0\,$.

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of showing that working through the Viete relations does lead to the desired conclusion, if we call the real zero $ \ r \ $ and the complex-conjugate zeroes $ \ a \pm bi \ \ , \ $ then the sum of the three zeroes is
$$ r \ + \ 2a \ = \ 0 \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ r \ \ = \ \ -2a \ \ ; $$
the sum of the pairwise-products of the zeroes is
$$ r·(a + bi) \ + \ r·(a - bi) \ + \ (a + bi)·(a - bi) \ \ = \ \ 2ar \ + \ (a^2 + b^2) $$ $$ = \ \ -4a^2 \ + \ (a^2 + b^2) \ \ = \ \ b^2 \ - \ 3a^2 \ \ = \ \ 2  \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ b^2 \ \ = \ \ 2 \ + \ 3a^2 \ \ ; $$
and finally the product of the zeroes is
$$ r·(a + bi)·(a - bi) \ \ = \ \ r·(a^2 + b^2) \ \ = \ \ (-2a)·(a^2 \ + \ 2  +  3a^2) \ \ = \ \ -1 $$
$$ \Rightarrow \ \ 2a·(4a^2 \ + \ 2 ) \ - \ 1 \ \ = \ \ 8a^3 \ + \ 4a \ - \ 1 \ \ = \ \ 0 \ \ . $$

(One *really* does not want to attack the given cubic equation directly, as the exact values of the zeroes are fully as hideous as the Cardano formula can make them -- rather surprising for such small integer coefficients...)